# Flutter app won't run on device and show the warning/error

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter, dart

```
 Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

 #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
 #1      _buildGradleProjectV2 (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:751:5) <asynchronous
 suspension>
 #2      buildGradleProject (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:494:14) <asynchronous
 suspension>
 #3      buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/apk.dart:34:9) <asynchronous suspension>
 #4      AndroidDevice.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:486:13)
 <asynchronous suspension>
 #5      FlutterDevice.runHot (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:378:54) <asynchronous
 suspension>
 #6      HotRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_hot.dart:254:39) <asynchronous suspension>
 #7      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:472:37) <asynchronous
 suspension>
 #8      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:490:18)
 #9      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
 #10     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
 #11     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
 #12     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
 #13     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
 #14     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
 #15     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
 #16     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:30:15)
 #17     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:288:13)
 #18     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
 #19     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
 #20     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
 #21     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
 #22     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
 #23     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
 #24     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
 #25     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
 #26     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:30:15)
 #27     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:288:13)
 #28     AndroidDevice.isLocalEmulator (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart)
 #29     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
 #30     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
 #31     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
 #32     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
 #33     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
 #34     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
 #35     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
 #36     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:552:7)
 #37     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
 #38     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
 #39     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
 #40     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
 #41     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
 #42     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
 #43     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:116:13)
 #44     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:173:5)
```

When I run "flutter run -v" and this details why my application
doesn't show on my device. I don't understand what that means, maybe
someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Setting you run or debug emulators device

`$ flutter emulators` your emulators list

- Nexus_5X_API_28     • Nexus 5X      • Google • Nexus 5X API 28
- Nexus_S_API_22      • Nexus S       • Google • Nexus S API 22
- flutter_emulator    • pixel         • Google apple_ios_simulator •
- iOS  Simulator • Apple

`$ flutter emulators --launch Nexus_5X_API_28` Nexus_5X_API_28 is you start emulators （Android or iOS emulators ）

`$ flutter run -v`

good luck

Comment: thank you for your response, i'll try it as soon as possible :D